# Installing Apache in different name and different port

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, apache2

If Linux server already has Apache web server running as httpd on port 80 to serve hosted website. and If I want to create a control panel to manage the server so I need to install a web server to serve the control panel GUI in different port for example :2083.

how to install second web server in different name in linux to serve the control panel GUI.

Comment: Note questions about hosting control panels are not welcome in SF. Web masters site may be more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

you can install [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) and edit the configuration files (****if on ubuntu****) that are in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` you can change where it says

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

and edit to what you need, from what you mentioned you could use

```
listen 2083 default_server;
listen [::]:2083 default_server;
```

**edit***
for SSL you can edit the line below it

```
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
```

and after you've done the one you need proceed by running this command (****if on ubuntu****) `systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: The question was cleary about *Apache HTTPD*, which he *already has*. If you have a knowledge of Apache, you can share it. If you don't, hmm, then why are you answering?

Comment: he mentioned "how to install second web server" which he already has apache and needs a different process name. if he were to use Nginx it would be a different process that also runs on a different port that also goes by a different process name. which I thought it would help his purpose but clearly it seems you know how to solve his issue so, hmm, why aren't you answering?